# Cocos2d - Overriding addChild for Child

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a class that inherits from CCNode. I want to override the adding of this class to a parent.

So if ClassA inherits CCNode, I add it like this `[self addChild:ClassA];`. ClassA contains 3 sprites and I want all 3 of those added when I add ClassA. Is there a way of doing this?

I looked into `addChild` and saw that it calls setParent on the child, so in ClassA I override setParent to do this:

```
- (void) setParent:(CCNode *)parent {
    [super setParent:parent];
    [parent addChild:_sprite1 z:kZClassA];
    [parent addChild:_sprite2 z:kZClassA];
    [parent addChild:_sprite3 z:kZClassA];
}
```

Seems kinda hacky to me? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to override `addChild` for this task.
All you have to do is add the sprites when you create them in `ClassA`. And when you will add `ClassA` as a child of a node then ClassA children will be automatically added as well. (Since they are the children of `ClassA`).

Assuming you create your sprites in the init method of `ClassA`:

```
- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
         // Create the sprites and then :
         [self addChild:sprite1]; // Add the sprite as a child of ClassA
         [self addChild:sprite2];
         [self addChild:sprite3];
    }

    return self;
}
```

then add `classA` to the desired node (Probably a `CCLayer` instance) :

```
[self addChild:classAInstance]; // Where self is an instance of your desired CCNode
```

Comment: Thanks I should've seen that.